# How to flow type component props and getDerivedStateFromProps if their props are different?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, flowtype

I have a `Component` with his *props* and I have one additional *prop* for `getDerivedStateFromProps`. So if I set *props* with additional one it throws an error that *prop* isn't used.
If I set without additional *prop* it throws an error that I can't put *prop* which isn't in component *props*:

```
type Props = {|
  name: string,
|};

type StaticProps = {|
  ...Props,
  surname: string,
|};

type State = {|
  name: string,
  surname: string,
|};

export class Foo extends Component<Props, State> {
  state: State = {
    name: '',
    surname: '',
  };

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props: StaticProps) {
    return { surname: props.surname };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.props.name}</div>
        <div>{this.state.surname}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

With this flow type throws an error: `Cannot create 'Foo' element because property 'surname' is missing in  'Props' [1] but exists in props [2].Flow(InferError)`.

If I set `Component<StaticProps, State>` it throws another error:
`'surname' PropType is defined but prop is never usedeslint(react/no-unused-prop-types)`

How can I flow type it properly?

Comment: Is `surname` a prop or a state? It seems like the two are being conflated, which might be causing issues.

Comment: which version of `eslint-plugin-react` are you using?

Comment: You are using getDerivedStateFromProps to update props with your state. If there is a difference, why are you using this method in the first place?

Comment: @user11307804 Surname is fetched from backend with redux and sagas. I don't need this field in global store, so copy it in local state

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings `7.12.4`

Comment: @NathanHall Yeah, in my case I need to get errors from the server and I need it in the local state because of frontend runtime errors and I don't want to store it in redux store, fewer dispatches, more speed and of course it should be local state

Comment: @ArtemBalamutyuk Have you set the react version in `.eslintrc`?

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings No, where I should set it?

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings Thank you, I set version in eslintrc and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it with @BoyWithSilverWings help, he proposed to set react version in `.eslintrc` and it works. Add just this to `.eslintrc` file:

```
"settings": {
  "react": {
    "version": "<your react version>" // 16.8.5
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just like the error tells you: `Props` has no attribute `surname` which you try to set initially. So you need to extend your type with that attribute:

```
type Props = {
  name: string,
  surname?: string
};
```

**Note**: You make use of two different Props-Types: `Props` used initially and `StaticProps` which is used inside of `getDerivedStateFromProps`. This does not really make sense in my eyes.

**Edit:** If you don't need all of the attributes defined in `Props` you can make them optional using the `?` charakter behind the attribute's name.

Comment: If I do it like that, it will throw an error: `'surname' PropType is defined but prop is never usedeslint(react/no-unused-prop-types)`

Comment: yes, because you do not use the same type. Use `Props` also in `mapStateToProps`

Comment: You mean `getDerivedStateFromProps`?

Comment: sorry, yes, thats what i meant

Comment: `Component` and `getDerivedStateFromProps` are like different instances and if I use some props inside `getDerivedStateFromProps` and don't use it inside other parts of component it will throw an error

Comment: you mix different types - thats why ts tells you that there are errors. Try to use `Props` everywhere and make `surname` optional using a `?`: `type Props = { name: string, surname?: string}`

Comment: But `surname` isn't optional, it must be passed in the component

Comment: @ArtemBalamutyuk does your current code equal the one above in your question?

Comment: No, I deleted some props from it and you maybe didn't get an error because of inexact props and I need exact